# Can an electromagnet be made from copper tape?

Tags: electromagnetic, copper

Can a roll of copper tape act like a solenoid when connected to electricity?

How does it compare to a solenoid of the same size made from copper wire?

[image: Text]

Answer (score 2):

Of course it can. There needs to be insulation between layers. Other than that, copper tape is just copper wire with high aspect ratio rectangular cross-section. Compared to small solenoids wound with thin wire, copper tape will have orders of magnitude lower resistance.

But you probably are asking in context of a particular application, so you won't get a particularly useful answer unless you get more specific.